# Regex: Select Everything Else

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to select everything what's not `[a-z0-9 ]`

So if the string is:

> Hello! How are you Mr. 007?

Then the result would be: `!,?,.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
[^a-z0-9]
```

You will also need a case-insensitive modifier, or alternatively use this: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Note that your expected result is incorrect: you missed the space character. If you want to also not match the space character you need to include it in the character class: `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]`.

Comment: hmm this works great!, I remembered something like this 10 minutes ago but I used wrongly, btw `^` isn't for `start of subject`? why the `[]` are changing this rule?

Comment: @CIRK: Because inside a character class there are different rules. E.g. most special characters in a expression (like `.`) have no special meaning a a character class.

Answer (score 2):

With `^` at the beginning of a character class, you negate that class:

```
str.match(/[^a-z0-9 ]/gi)
```

You should also add space (or `\s` (which is space, tab,...)) and the modifier `i` to make the match case insensitive.

Read more about [regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [regular expressions in general](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).